# Is there a way to get an ILogger instance inside an extension methods?

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection

I have a static class with extension methods. It used to be a regular class so I took advantage of constructor injection to inject `ILogger` for logging inside the methods.

After converting the methods to extension methods, I initially added `ILogger` as a parameter because of the static nature of the class.

```
public static string Overflow(this string message, ..., ILogger logger = null)
{
    ...
    logger?.LogInformation("Stack");
}
```

But having to pass an instance of `ILogger` as an argument anytime the extension method is called has become tiring.
It should be noted that logging inside these methods is handy but not required therefore, I would want to log only if there is a logger instance registered.

Is there a way to get an instance of `ILogger` inside the extension methods?

Something like this

```
public static string Overflow(this string message, ...)
{
    ...
    // Log if there is a registered logger instance available
}
```

Comment: what if you dont pass the parameter and check of `null` before using it?

Comment: @viveknuna Could you explain further?

Answer (score 2):

You could . . .

1. Create an `ILogger` in your static class using a static constructor, but that might be painful because static constructors cannot take arguments, so you'll have to build the ILogger from scratch.
2. Create a separate class that has the ILogger you want and write static functions on that class to access the logger. Then call these functions from inside your extension method. We do something similar in the place I call my "day job." We have a static class that has the logger, so we can call `MyCompanyLogger.LogInformation(...)` from virtually anywhere.

Comment: With option 2, do you mean I should create a class and inject `ILogger` into the constructor, and expose it using `static` methods of the class?

Comment: @Jeffery sure. You can inject it into that class or build it inside. Dealer’s choice.